# Google recaptcha missing-input-response

Tags: php, recaptcha

I have an error with the response of Google recaptcha.
Please, could you help me to find my error ?

```
function captcha(){
    $secret = "...";
    $response = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    $remoteip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $api_url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secret."&response=".$response."&remoteip=".$remoteip;
    $decode = json_decode(file_get_contents($api_url), true);
    if ($decode['success'] == true) {
        return $decode['success'];
    }else{
        $errorsCode = "";
        foreach ($decode['error-codes'] as $key => $value) {
            $errorsCode .= '<p><strong>' . $key.':</strong> '.$value.'</p>';
        }
        return $errorsCode;
    }
}
```

I get always the same error : missing-input-response.

Thank you for your help !

**EDIT** : Solved with https://gist.github.com/jonathanstark/dfb30bdfb522318fc819 by **Mrpink**

Comment: Build upon already available solutions. Have a look at this https://gist.github.com/jonathanstark/dfb30bdfb522318fc819

Comment: This is also interesting https://github.com/google/recaptcha/blob/master/examples/example-captcha.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recaptcha missing-input-response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42327694/recaptcha-missing-input-response)

Comment: Thank you very much Mrpink !! My problem is solved !